# php:opendir fails in safari

Tags: php, safari, opendir

I have a file browser,on a Linux server,which displays subdirectories and files of a directory.The code goes like this:

```
 if (!isset($_GET['currentdirectory'])){
            $rootDirectory=opendir("./documents");
          }
        else {
            $currentDirectory = $_GET['currentdirectory'];
            $rootDirectory=opendir($currentDirectory);
          }         
        starter($rootDirectory);
```

Function starter reads the directory contents and prints them.
When I use Internet Explorer,Firefox or Chrome to open the filebrowser,all subdirectories and files are displayed as they are,but when I'm doing the same with Safari, opendir fails for some subdirectories(not all),so they seem as they are empty.
Could anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

php is run on the/a server, browser version does not matter. It is something with the UI not php.